# Running two MCMC chains in parallel while minimizing Kullback-Leibler divergence between both sample distributions

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, markov-process, autoregressive, kullback-leibler

I want to sample from a distribution $p(X)$ with $X \in R^n$. However, I can only evaluate the likelihoods of $Z = AX$ and $Z = BX$ with $A,B \in R^{m \times n}$ and $m = n-1$.

Now my idea is to run two Markov Chain Monte Carlo samplers in parallel while minimizing the Kullback-Leibler divergence of the sample-approximated distributions of both chains.

I was thinking of some kind of autoregressive proposal distribution that becomes tighter when the approximated distribution of a chain is wider than that of the other chain (and vice versa).

Is this feasible? Does anyone know an existing algorithm that does something similar? I would be very happy about any expert opinion on that.

Comment: I don't quite understand the second part of your question (the one about the AR proposal distribution), but the first has been done in this paper by Dixit and Roy: https://vroy.public.iastate.edu/Research/KLDiag.pdf